# An Error Has Occurred Running Scripts On This Page - Repairing issue with batch script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation

If you've been using ArcGIS for a while, you will have most likely come across this error:

[image]

The issue is linked to some sort of ActiveX plugin security setting in the 32 bit version of Internet Explorer. A quick fix is to go into the Security settings of IE and change it from Medium high to Medium, and the problem will be resolved. This is all fine and dandy, I've made the change on my home laptop and there are no more script errors there.

However, my main issue is that on my work computer, the administrators have set the machines up so that any changes done during the session are reverted after a logoff or reboot. It's tiring to open the Internet security settings every day - Is there a way to write a batch or python script that will do this automatically?

Comment: Can IT add your workstation to a different security group or provide you with enhanced security privileges?

Comment: You could also use a different browser - Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.

Comment: I've tried requesting it, but they won't allow a permanent change to the security settings. @recurvata the issue is that ArcGIS depends on IE settings. I use Chrome.

Comment: The link in this question appears to be broken.